# Should [notation] and [symbolism] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [symbolism] tag now has two questions.  In my opinion, symbolism and notation are the same thing, and it makes sense that their tags should be synonyms.  Does anyone disagree, or is any moderator willing to do this?  A possibly related question is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-should-we-handle-tags-terminology-notation-definition).

Comment: possibly related, though I'm not sure how closely: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-should-we-handle-tags-terminology-notation-definition

Comment: @Isaac: That's the same question Paul linked to in his final sentence.